# How can it be proven that $\operatorname{li}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(\log⁡ x)$?

Tags: improper-integrals

How to show that $\operatorname{li}(x)=\operatorname{Ei}(\log x)$?

Here, $\operatorname{li}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ are defined as:
$$\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\log t}$$
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^t}t\,\mathrm dt$$
I can't find any proof of this expression but I did find many articles stating it, could anyone show me how it could be proven?

Comment: Substitute $y=\log(t)$ and use $\text{Ei}(y)$’s integral representation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prove:
$$
\int _{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\log(t)} \, dt==\int _{-\infty}^{\log(x)} \frac{e^{ t }}{t} \, dt  
$$
Let left-hand side $t=e^{ u }$
So,
$$
\int _{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\log(t)} \, dt = \int _{-\infty}^{\log(x)} \frac{1}{u} \cdot e^{ u } \, du  
$$
Done.